# http headers are not mutable in flutter

Tags: dart

I am using this code to send http request using Dart:

```
var request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      Map jsonMap = {'pageSize': 10};
      request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
      request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
      var response = await request.close();
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
}
```

but it shows:

```
HttpException: HTTP headers are not mutable
```

why give me this tips and what should I do fix this?

Comment: Which library are you using to send the post request? For example in the `http` package you need to set the headers *BEFORE* sending the request

Answer (score 1):

You need to check HttpHeaders class page. (https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-io/HttpHeaders-class.html)

> HttpRequest and HttpClientResponse always have immutable headers.
> HttpResponse and HttpClientRequest have immutable headers from the moment the body is written to.

```
request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
```

This line is add Request Body so made HttpClientRequest header to immutable. So if you want to add headers, you need to do it before this line.

```
var request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      Map jsonMap = {'pageSize': 10};
      request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
      request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));
      var response = await request.close();
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
}
```